# When to manually re-calculate indices statistics

Tags: indexing, firebird, indices, table-statistics

I have an application which stores continuous data. Rows are then selected based on two columns (`timestamp` and `integer`).

To keep the performance as good as possible, I have to recalculate statistics for indices, but I have two problems with recalculating based on time interval:

1. The amount of rows inserted per day could be **very** different. It could be ten rows on one installation and millions of rows on another one.
2. There is no guarantee that the application runs 24/7. It could run for example only for one hour per day or even once per week.

I read that it is good to recalculate index statistics once per day in the time with minimum load and it is great advice for some web or company database, but this is completely different situation, so I would like to add some "intelligence" into auto recalculating.

Is there some number (42; 1,000; 1,000,000 ?) of rows per table after which the statistics should be recalculated? Is it depends also on the total number of rows currently in the table?

Comment: if you have a spare time, then it would be better to destroy the index and rebuild it from scratch. It is either made be `drop` and `create` or by `alter index NAME inactive` and then `alter ... active`

Comment: Also think about batch inserts. If you don't need a real time reaction it could make sense to create temporary non-indexed files (maybe as External Tables) and on schedule (like every 5 minutes) a special daemon makes sure everyone stops reading from the data table, then deactivates indices, then bulk-insert the data from temporary accumulators, then re-activate indices and then clear those accumulators and then enable other programs from reading the table again. SQL is not well suited for direct insertion of regularly generated data like hardware sensors, you better decouple it

Comment: @Arioch'The thank you, I already have there some sort of queue from which I insert many rows in `execute block` at once. But I do that without indices deactivation.

Comment: then you have the index tree being changed  for every row, and the tree is swinging between "fastly changed dysfunctional one-side-leaning" and "re-balanced, partially rebuild into less dysfunctional state, with much of time invested" And you do it again and again. If you really do have to do massive "bulk inserts" - then sometimes it gets overall faster to just put the work on hold, kill indexes, insert really lots of data, and build indexes anew.

Comment: Additionally, if your database becomes slow - then there may be other reasons, like bad transactions management. You look about some FAQ about generic reasons of firebird getting slow, like OIT/OAT/NT gap running out of control amok, etc.

Comment: @Arioch'The thank you for your tips. As I wrote, I don't have databases under my control and the number of rows inserted could be very different and that is the reason, why I thought that it is not so bad idea to deal with statistics more based on number of rows than time, or to do something with every "bulk insert" (since it doesn't have to be bulk at all).

Answer (score 1):

Server uses statistics to select best possible index from available ones. Check plan of your query on non empty database. If it is optimal with current statistics and relative data distribution doesn't vary with time or there are just no other indices to choose from then there is no need in forced recalculation.

Other approach involve either direct specification of optimal plan with the query text or usage of arithmetic operations to exclude index on some field from evaluation regardless of actual statistics.

For example, if query contains condition:

```
  table_1.some_field = table_2.some_field
```

and you don't want server to use index on field table_1.some_field then write:

```
  table_1.some_field + 0 = table_2.some_field
```

This way you could force server to use one index over another.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the part about data distribution. Since the data are saved continuously I would say, that the data distribution changes over time.

Comment: @Artholl Current versions of Firebird don't have very extensive statistics (no histograms, just basic selectivity information), so if you have statistics of a representative population of your database, then it is usually not  necessary to calculate statistics often, because Firebird selects indexes based on comparing the selectivity of relevant indexes, and although the actual selectivity might change, it would probably not change the relative difference between selectivity of various indexes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you. The representative population is something I am not able to easily obtain, because one column could have value from around a thousand different values. It could be only the one value on one installation and thousand values on another. The problem is, that this could change over time and in that case it completely ruins saved selectivity.